# question about throwing an object

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A() {std::cout<<"A() ";}
    A(const A& a){cout<<"A(const A&) ";}
    ~A(){cout<<"~A() ";}

    virtual void Foo(){cout<<"A::Foo() ";}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(){std::cout<<"B() ";}
    B(const B& a){cout<<"B(const B&) ";}
    ~B(){cout<<"~B() ";}

    virtual void Foo() {cout<<"B::Foo() ";}

};

int main()
{
    try{
         B b;
         throw b;                        //throw like this
    }
    catch(A ex){
        ex.Foo();
    }
    catch(B ex){
        ex.Foo();
    }
    catch(A * ex){
        ex->Foo();
    }
    catch(B * ex){
        ex->Foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

A() B() A() B(const B&) ~B() ~A() A(const A&) A::Foo() ~A() ~B() ~A()

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A{
public:
    A() {std::cout<<"A() ";}
    A(const A& a){cout<<"A(const A&) ";}
    ~A(){cout<<"~A() ";}

    virtual void Foo(){cout<<"A::Foo() ";}
};

class B: public A
{
public:
    B(){std::cout<<"B() ";}
    B(const B& a){cout<<"B(const B&) ";}
    ~B(){cout<<"~B() ";}

    virtual void Foo() {cout<<"B::Foo() ";}

};

int main()
{
    try{

         throw B();              //throw it this way
    }
    catch(A ex){
        ex.Foo();
    }
    catch(B ex){
        ex.Foo();
    }
    catch(A * ex){
        ex->Foo();
    }
    catch(B * ex){
        ex->Foo();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

A() B() A(const A&) A::Foo() ~A() ~B() ~A()

Can anybody explain the difference to me?
The difference is

A() B(const B&) ~B() ~A()

Why is the copy constructor of class B invoked?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because in the first sample the local variable `b` is first being copied at the `throw` line, and then sliced at the `catch ( A ex )` line, while in the second sample only the second copy is performed.

I think I have to mention the [throw by value, catch by reference](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=373339) mantra here :)

Comment: then why the constructor of A is called first before the copy constructor of class B?

Comment: Base constructor always gets called before one of the derived class. That's why you can't call virtual functions (and expect derived code to run) in base ctor/dtor.

Comment: Because B's copy constructor doesn't explicitly copy the base, so the base is default-constructed. `B(const B& a): A(a) {cout<<"B(const B&) ";}` GCC warns both about this behavior and that the handler for A will catch the exception before handler for B gets a chance.

Comment: @skydoor: because B's copy ctor still has to construct the `A` part of the object, and you didn't have anything in the initializer list for the copy ctor to tell it how to construct the `A` part of the object, so it used the default constructor for `A`.